# Good MDX default query

Tags: mdx, olap, mondrian

I have build an MDX editor and now need a good default query which executes and already has two dimensions. I would like to place the measures on the first dimension (without knowing their names), and any other cube dimension on the second result dimension. Currently I have achived this:

```
select {[Measures].members} ON COLUMNS
  from [mycubename]
```

But I don't know how to populate the second column... Any Ideas?

Something like

```
select {[Measures].members} ON COLUMNS,
       {[Dimensions].[first].members} ON ROWS  
  from [mycubename]
```

which would work against any cube if the cube name is given in the from clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works in Microsoft SSAS, so you may need to tweak the syntax for Mondrian:

```
SELECT Measures.DefaultMember ON COLUMNS,
Dimensions(1).Members ON ROWS
FROM [Cube]
```